How to improve gcc compile time for compile-once single file program
GCC version: 11.4.0
Flags I am passing: -O3 -march=native -funroll-all-loops -mprefer-vector-width=512 -mavx
I have a C program that looks like this:
void foo(...) {
  for (int i...)
    for (int j...)
      for (int k...)
        ... <some loop body>
}

int main() {
  ... <some setup>
  foo(...);
  ... <many invocations of foo>
  foo(...);
  <print some info>
}

That ends up being like 100k lines of code (by virtue of the many calls to foo).
Using -ftime-report, I get:
Time variable                                   usr           sys          wall           GGC
 phase setup                        :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  2510k (  0%)
 phase parsing                      :   0.91 (  0%)   2.96 ( 52%)   3.88 (  0%)    39M (  5%)
 phase opt and generate             :4559.51 (100%)   2.77 ( 48%)4562.80 (100%)   696M ( 94%)
 garbage collection                 :   0.09 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.08 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 callgraph construction             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.05 (  0%)    49M (  7%)
 callgraph optimization             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)  2104  (  0%)
 callgraph functions expansion      :4557.69 (100%)   2.05 ( 36%)4560.27 (100%)   382M ( 52%)
 callgraph ipa passes               :   1.74 (  0%)   0.70 ( 12%)   2.43 (  0%)   267M ( 36%)
 ipa function summary               :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    13k (  0%)
 ipa dead code removal              :   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 ipa cp                             :   0.07 (  0%)   0.27 (  5%)   0.31 (  0%)   199M ( 27%)
 ipa inlining heuristics            :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)   640  (  0%)
 ipa reference                      :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 ipa pure const                     :   0.04 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)  1344  (  0%)
 ipa icf                            :   0.05 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 ipa SRA                            :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   800  (  0%)
 ipa free inline summary            :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 ipa modref                         :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1056  (  0%)
 trivially dead code                :   0.40 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.42 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 df scan insns                      :   0.33 (  0%)   0.10 (  2%)   0.43 (  0%)   144  (  0%)
 df reaching defs                   :   1.56 (  0%)   0.22 (  4%)   1.82 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 df live regs                       :   2.54 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   2.55 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 df live&initialized regs           :   0.30 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.31 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 df must-initialized regs           :   0.04 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 df use-def / def-use chains        :   0.27 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.28 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
df reg dead/unused notes           :   1.54 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   1.51 (  0%)    36M (  5%)                                           [48/83]
 register information               :   0.30 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.29 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 alias analysis                     :   0.68 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.68 (  0%)    63k (  0%)
 alias stmt walking                 :   0.18 (  0%)   0.46 (  8%)   0.66 (  0%)    16k (  0%)
 register scan                      :   0.09 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.10 (  0%)    64  (  0%)
 rebuild jump labels                :   0.16 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.16 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.23 (  0%)   0.68 ( 12%)   0.97 (  0%)  7074k (  1%)
 lexical analysis                   :   0.39 (  0%)   1.41 ( 25%)   1.79 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 parser (global)                    :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1082k (  0%)
 parser function body               :   0.29 (  0%)   0.86 ( 15%)   1.11 (  0%)    31M (  4%)
 parser inl. func. body             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   172k (  0%)
 early inlining heuristics          :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  6888  (  0%)
 inline parameters                  :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.07 (  0%)  8198k (  1%)
 integration                        :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)    35k (  0%)
 tree gimplify                      :   0.06 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)    28M (  4%)
 tree eh                            :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1384  (  0%)
 tree tail merge                    :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1856  (  0%)
 tree VRP                           :   0.06 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)    59k (  0%)
 tree Early VRP                     :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    21k (  0%)
 tree copy propagation              :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   144  (  0%)
 tree PTA                           :   1.16 (  0%)   0.15 (  3%)   1.32 (  0%)  3278k (  0%)
 tree SSA rewrite                   :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  9427k (  1%)
 tree SSA other                     :   0.01 (  0%)   0.06 (  1%)   0.05 (  0%)   808  (  0%)
 tree SSA incremental               :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  4216  (  0%)
 tree operand scan                  :   0.03 (  0%)   0.03 (  1%)   0.06 (  0%)    16M (  2%)
 dominator optimization             :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    25k (  0%)
 tree CCP                           :   0.04 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)  3880  (  0%)
 tree reassociation                 :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   136  (  0%)
 tree PRE                           :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.07 (  0%)    20k (  0%)
 tree FRE                           :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)  6928  (  0%)
 tree code sinking                  :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  1216  (  0%)
 tree linearize phis                :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  3216  (  0%)
 tree forward propagate             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  1896  (  0%)df reg dead/unused notes           :   1.54 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   1.51 (  0%)    36M (  5%)                                           [48/83]
 register information               :   0.30 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.29 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 alias analysis                     :   0.68 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.68 (  0%)    63k (  0%)
 alias stmt walking                 :   0.18 (  0%)   0.46 (  8%)   0.66 (  0%)    16k (  0%)
 register scan                      :   0.09 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.10 (  0%)    64  (  0%)
 rebuild jump labels                :   0.16 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.16 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.23 (  0%)   0.68 ( 12%)   0.97 (  0%)  7074k (  1%)
 lexical analysis                   :   0.39 (  0%)   1.41 ( 25%)   1.79 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 parser (global)                    :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1082k (  0%)
 parser function body               :   0.29 (  0%)   0.86 ( 15%)   1.11 (  0%)    31M (  4%)
 parser inl. func. body             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   172k (  0%)
 early inlining heuristics          :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  6888  (  0%)
 inline parameters                  :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.07 (  0%)  8198k (  1%)
 integration                        :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)    35k (  0%)
 tree gimplify                      :   0.06 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)    28M (  4%)
 tree eh                            :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1384  (  0%)
 tree tail merge                    :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  1856  (  0%)
 tree VRP                           :   0.06 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.06 (  0%)    59k (  0%)
 tree Early VRP                     :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    21k (  0%)
 tree copy propagation              :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   144  (  0%)
 tree PTA                           :   1.16 (  0%)   0.15 (  3%)   1.32 (  0%)  3278k (  0%)
 tree SSA rewrite                   :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  9427k (  1%)
 tree SSA other                     :   0.01 (  0%)   0.06 (  1%)   0.05 (  0%)   808  (  0%)
 tree SSA incremental               :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  4216  (  0%)
 tree operand scan                  :   0.03 (  0%)   0.03 (  1%)   0.06 (  0%)    16M (  2%)
 dominator optimization             :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    25k (  0%)
 tree CCP                           :   0.04 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)  3880  (  0%)
 tree reassociation                 :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   136  (  0%)
 tree PRE                           :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.07 (  0%)    20k (  0%)
 tree FRE                           :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)  6928  (  0%)
 tree code sinking                  :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  1216  (  0%)
 tree linearize phis                :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  3216  (  0%)
 tree forward propagate             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)  1896  (  0%)
tree conservative DCE              :   0.08 (  0%)   0.17 (  3%)   0.33 (  0%)  1192  (  0%)                                           [15/83]
 tree aggressive DCE                :   0.09 (  0%)   0.12 (  2%)   0.15 (  0%)    10k (  0%)
 tree DSE                           :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   680  (  0%)
 tree slp vectorization             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  7816  (  0%)
 tree iv optimization               :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   170k (  0%)
 gimple widening/fma detection      :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   776  (  0%)
 tree strlen optimization           :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)    23k (  0%)
 out of ssa                         :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   688  (  0%)
 expand vars                        :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  2465k (  0%)
 expand                             :   0.23 (  0%)   0.09 (  2%)   0.32 (  0%)   191M ( 26%)
 post expand cleanups               :   0.04 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)  6664  (  0%)
 forward prop                       :   0.62 (  0%)   0.34 (  6%)   0.95 (  0%)  2104  (  0%)
 CSE                                :   0.26 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.24 (  0%)  1584  (  0%)
 dead code elimination              :   0.31 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.34 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 dead store elim1                   :1753.10 ( 38%)   0.14 (  2%)1753.46 ( 38%)    19M (  3%)
 dead store elim2                   :1723.95 ( 38%)   0.00 (  0%)1724.15 ( 38%)    19M (  3%)
 loop invariant motion              :   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   112  (  0%)
 loop unrolling                     :   0.09 (  0%)   0.03 (  1%)   0.10 (  0%)   113k (  0%)
 CPROP                              :   0.67 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.68 (  0%)    18k (  0%)
 PRE                                :   0.07 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.08 (  0%)  5736  (  0%)
 web                                :   0.13 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.14 (  0%)  2016  (  0%)
 CSE 2                              :   0.12 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.12 (  0%)  2688  (  0%)
 branch prediction                  :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  6920  (  0%)
 combiner                           : 105.87 (  2%)   0.02 (  0%) 105.87 (  2%)  2486k (  0%)
 integrated RA                      :   1.42 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   1.44 (  0%)   211k (  0%)
 LRA non-specific                   :   0.47 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   0.49 (  0%)    14k (  0%)
 LRA virtuals elimination           :   0.09 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.08 (  0%)  2232  (  0%)
 LRA reload inheritance             :   0.14 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.14 (  0%)  3024  (  0%)
 LRA create live ranges             :   0.39 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.39 (  0%)  2376  (  0%)
 LRA rematerialization              :   0.11 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.12 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 reload CSE regs                    : 955.65 ( 21%)   0.00 (  0%) 955.74 ( 21%)  9848k (  1%)
 load CSE after reload              :   0.09 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.10 (  0%)   440  (  0%)
 ree                                :   0.08 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.08 (  0%)   288  (  0%)
thread pro- & epilogue             :   0.23 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.22 (  0%)  7864  (  0%)
 combine stack adjustments          :   0.05 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 peephole 2                         :   0.12 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.11 (  0%)    39k (  0%)
 rename registers                   :   0.53 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.54 (  0%)  2016  (  0%)
 hard reg cprop                     :   0.17 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.17 (  0%)   192  (  0%)
 scheduling 2                       :   2.36 (  0%)   0.35 (  6%)   2.71 (  0%)    72M ( 10%)
 machine dep reorg                  :   0.34 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)   0.34 (  0%)  4680  (  0%)
 reorder blocks                     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)  5024  (  0%)
 shorten branches                   :   0.18 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.19 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 final                              :   0.29 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.29 (  0%)    28M (  4%)
 rest of compilation                :   0.47 (  0%)   0.08 (  1%)   0.55 (  0%)    16k (  0%)
 remove unused locals               :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 address taken                      :   0.04 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.05 (  0%)     0  (  0%)
 TOTAL                              :4560.42          5.73       4566.68          738M

Compilation time is 76 mins.
How could I speed up compilation time?
Looking at the compile time profiling:

I am surprised that a lot of time is taken by dead store elimination considering that I don't have dead code (is dead store different?)
Does reload CSE regs imply that registers are CSEd and then the CSE is undone?

Messing around with -O flags:

Compilation time: O1 faster than O2, O2 similar to O3
Execution time: O1 similar to O2, O2 much worse than O3

So I think I have to stick to -O3.

What problem are you trying to solve? Why is the compile time so important?  I think it is the least important issue

Particularly when just dealing with 20k LoC which is a relatively small program. Full build of some 2M LoC... that's when compilation times might get a bit annoying (or a convenient excuse to go grab more coffee).

"Dead store" is different, it means storing values that are then never read again. Waste of time, so the compiler will try to avoid that.

The obvious first things to try are -O2 and -O1.  They should make compilation faster, and you can see whether there's a significant reduction in the program's performance.  If you really want to make compilation faster, -O0.

You might want to look more carefully at why it is having to work so hard eliminating "dead store" code. Or back off the optimisation to -O2 from -O3. BTW -funroll-all-loops doesn't always make faster code sometimes the compiler knows best which ones will benefit from unrolling (or inlining). The last 20% improvement in performance costs roughly ~80% of compile time.

Since you've compiled the code once to get the timings, why do you need to worry any more about the compilation time?  Presumably, you're not actually compiling once but multiple times while you get the code sufficiently right, and you'll do more compilations when you need to enhance the code, and so on.  Or will you have other vaguely similar programs to build and want to keep the compilation times down for those?  For your described scenario, you are wasting your angst.  There may well be other scenarios where your concerns are justified.

Old guards here probably remember times when building project could take whole night or even more :)

@NateEldredge Added details to the question about using O2 and O1.

@JonathanLeffler I generate such code for multiple programs and benchmark them. And I often have to tweak the codegen a little. If my programs are taking an hour to compile, for multiple programs the turnaround time to check if my new codegen is actually better is too long.

I have updated the question with details of a larger but similar program that I generate, that takes over an hour to compile to make it more evident why I want to improve compile times.

@PratyushDas — your explanation in the comments makes sense.  You're repeatedly compiling programs that take too long to compile.  It's not much different from compiling variations on a single program as you develop that single program.  You'd do well to indicate how long the compilation takes and to drop the emphasis on 'compile-once'.  You're compiling repeatedly.

You could consider to compile gcc itself with your flags and -flto. https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2013-03/msg00215.html I wonder if there are modern measurements. Also try -Os.

As far as I understand, you want to optimize for host performance / compile time (as opposed to optimize for the program being compiled).
Then -O0 is your friend, maybe in combination with -g0 (no debug info). Next closest is -Og (optimize without impeding debugging experience).
